# search the column with decimal value for '.'

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal, floor, ceil

I have a table with a1 and a2 float columns,

The values in a2 are calculated from a1, as a2 = 3*a1

The condition is:

If the value in a1 is 9.5, I need to get the ceiling value in a2
i.e., if the numeric value after the decimal point is greater than or equal to 5 I need to get ceiling value, else I need to get the floor value.

I have written below query

```
SET    a2 =(case when substring(cast((a1 * 3) as varchar(6)),CHARINDEX('.',(a1*3)),1) >=5 then CEILING(a1 * 3) else FLOOR(a1 * 3) end) from table
```

but it obviously returns the below error:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '.' to data type int.

Since it, can't take varchar into ceiling or floor.

Is there any way by which I can achieve this?

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

The value of a2 keeps changing based on a1, if a1 is 4.5 a2 should ceiling of that, if a1 is 4.9 a2 should be again ceiling value but if a1 is anything below 4.5 as 4.3,4.2,4.1 then it should be a floor value

Any other approach for this would also do except ceiling and floor.

Comment: Put a convert inside your ceiling and floor

Comment: Please edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.  There may be better ways to do what you want.

Comment: as @GordonLinoff answered, what you describe is what ROUND function does.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `round()`?  It implements this logic directly in the database:

```
set a2 = round(a1, 0);
```

An alternative method is to subtract 0.5:

```
set a2 = floor(a1 + 0.5)
```

If you want `a2` as a string value (you say you want a float but the code returns a string), then use `str()`:

```
set a2 = str(a1)
```

`str()` rounds by default.

Comment: if i use round (4.5,1) it gives me 4.5, but for round(4.9) i need 5 and not 4.9

Comment: use round(4.5). it should round your number.

Comment: The value of a2 keeps changing based on a1 , if a1 is 4.5 a2 should ceiling of that , if a1 is 4.9 a2 should be again ceiling value but if a1 is anything below 4.5 as 4.3,4.2,4.1 then it should be a floor value

Comment: sorry, the correct syntax is `ROUND(number, precision)`. to round to an int use `ROUND(4.5, 0)`.

Comment: I think your alternative method should read, `set a2 = floor(a1 + 0.5)`, so that e.g. 4.2 gives `floor(4.7) = 4` and 4.6 gives `floor(5.1) = 5`. Either that, or use `ceiling` not `floor`. In any case, I think `round(a2, 0)` is likely to be the most efficient. Also, if a1 is always the rounded value, why is it a `float` and not an `int`? If it were an `int`, you could just `set a1 = a2 + 0.5` directly, and the implicit type conversion and integer truncation would give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

That because you trying to compare varchar >=5, cast it to INT:

```
SET a2 =(case when cast(substring(cast((a1 * 3) as varchar(6)),CHARINDEX('.',(cast((a1 * 3) as varchar(6))),1) as INT) >=5 then CEILING(a1 * 3) else FLOOR(a1 * 3) end) from table
```